# Insert into with 2 (multiple) select?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

What I am trying to do is something like this :

```
INSERT INTO LIVRE (id_livre, id_client, id_produit)
VALUES (
  null,
  SELECT id_client from CLIENT where distributeur like "%Traffic%", 
  SELECT id_produit from PRODUIT where num_serie_produit = 1401000
);
```

Is it possible with 1 SELECT ?

I tried something like :

```
INSERT INTO LIVRE (id_livre,id_client,id_produit) 
SELECT
  null,
  C.id_client,
  P.id_produit 
FROM
  LIVRE, CLIENT C, PRODUIT P
WHERE
  C.distributeur like "%Traffic%"
  AND P.num_serie_produit = 1401000;
```

but I dont know how to write it correctly :/

I searched but I couldn't find really what i want. So sorry if someone already asked it.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if your `SELECT` returns more than 1 rows? How do you handle that case?

Comment: for the num_serie_produit its not possible (its a PK) but for the distributeur its totally possible :/ If I put -> c.distributeur = "Traffic Systems" <- (its the only exact name so no other like this one). Its should be good ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something similar to.

```
 INSERT INTO c (aID, bID) 
 SELECT a.ID, B.ID 
 FROM A, B 
 WHERE A.Name='Nisha'
 AND B.Class='Java';
```

In your case, it would be:  (**JUST REMOVE LIVRE  FROM WHERE CLAUSE**)

```
INSERT INTO LIVRE (id_livre,id_client,id_produit) 
SELECT null, C.id_client,P.id_produit 
FROM CLIENT C, PRODUIT P
WHERE C.distributeur like "%Traffic%"
    AND P.num_serie_produit = 1401000;
```

---

Assuming that there will be only one row returned from select query,If more than 1 row returned by select query, then use rownum or limit function as appropriate to below query.

```
INSERT INTO LIVRE (id_livre, id_client, id_produit)
VALUES 
(null, 
(SELECT id_client from *CLIENT* where distributeur like "%Traffic%"), 
(SELECT id_produit from *PRODUIT* where num_serie_produit = 1401000) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. I modified a lil bit to make sure that will return only 1 row.

Comment: @Booba__2012: Thank you. You can may be upvote and accept this as the answer by selecting the grey tick box next to this answer!